# Visual Studio Code hint 'namespace "pqxx" has no member "work"' when use libpqxx installed via vcpkg

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, vscode-extensions, vcpkg

I'm using Libpqxx 7.7.3 installed via vcpkg which after importing **compiles just fine** but Visual Studio Code hinting breaks and underlines errors even though what I did is all standard to the documentation provided by libpqxx.

I tried out Boost and currently I am using Poco without problems via vcpkg and vscode type hinting works, this issue only appears when using libpqxx.

To reproduce:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
./vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
./vcpkg/vcpkg install libpq[openssl]
./vcpkg/vcpkg install libpqxx
```

CMakeLists.txt

```sh
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)
project(MyProject VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

#include_directories(BEFORE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include")

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(libpqxx CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE libpqxx::pqxx)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE PostgreSQL::PostgreSQL)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)
# Poco stuff ...
```

The incorrect linting:

```c++
#include <pqxx/pqxx> 
// ...

 pqxx::connection connection(uri.c_str()); // incomplete type is not allowed
 pqxx::work tx(conn); // namespace "pqxx" has no member "work"
// ...
```

The problem might be the C++ version syntax?

Libpqxx getting started example: https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/7.2.1/a01350.html

Configure until now was successful via terminal

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${PWD}\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake"
```

Additional vscode config files that may be relevant:

c_cpp_properties.json (C/C++ extension)

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
            "forcedInclude": [],
            "browse": {
                "path": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

settings.json

```json
//...
  "cmake.platform": "",
    "cmakeLanguageSupport.enableFileAPI": true,
    "cmake.autoSelectActiveFolder": true,
    "cmake.skipConfigureIfCachePresent": false,
    "cmake.configureSettings": {"CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE":"<path>/vcpkg.cmake"}
```

Comment: Are you using the CMakeTools extension in VSCode?

Comment: @drescherjm I am using CMake Tools extension v1.11.26. I however do the configure via terminal `cmake CMakeLists.txt "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${PWD}\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake" --debug-find`. Would this be the issue?

Comment: Don't configure cmake by hand if you are using CMake Tools extension, it likely defeats all the mechanism between CMake Tools and C/C++ extension (or clangd extension), because the later relies on generation of compile_commands.json for syntax coloration.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes Cmake Tools extension often times seems to fail at finding installed libraries. I tried looking through settings to see if there is anything to modify it’s configure options but without success

Comment: Hard to help you without more information. Do you set `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<path/to/vcpkg.cmake>` in `cmake.configureArgs` of your `settings.json`?

Comment: Upon doing CTRL+SHIFT+P and running `C/C++: Log Diagnostics` I found that it enumerated includes also per file, and on the problem file in the src directory it wrote just the basic includes. So after that I did something stupid, in CMakeLists.txt at add_executable I appended all my files src files.. and ran configure again, then build which of course failed but the lint errors were gone. After that I reverted the add_executable to just main.cpp since it imports every other source file and re-ran configure and build via CMake Tools again. The lint errors did not come back.

Comment: The steps I listed in above comment fixed it, however this doesn't feel like an answer. CMake Tools and C/C++ extensions are supposed to just work together but it seems on Linux this might not be a priority? To clarify: Even after CMake Tools Configure and Build both ran successfully, the C/C++ extension did not work properly. Will add the C/C++ extension tag if it exists to the question.

Comment: And a similar issue I found on cpp-tools repo which led me to the Log Diagnostics command. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5266

Comment: I can't help you with C/C++ extension, but I advice to disable its intellisense (`"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Disabled"` in `settings.json`) and rely on clangd extension instead. Anyway, a `c_cpp_properties.json` shouldn't be needed for syntax highlighting when you use CMake Tools, maybe it causes conflicts with information provided by CMake (`compile_commands.json`?) to C/C++ extension?